# Passing authorization bearer token using BreezeJS OData data service

Tags: oauth, odata, breeze

How do I tell Breeze to include an authorization bearer token header when using the OData data service?

```
//Configured breeze to use OData
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'OData');

//Configured breeze to use AngularJS ajax
var instance = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular', true);

//Tried passing authorization bearer token header using setHttp with no success
//NOTE: $http setup with $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer...'
instance.setHttp($http);

//Tried passing authorization bearer token header using ajax settings with no success
instance.defaultSettings = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer...'
    },
};

//Fiddler shows no authorization bearer token header for following query
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('/odata/');
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Customers');
return manager.executeQuery(query).to$q(querySucceeded, queryFailed);
```

Comment: did you ever solve your problem ? I've got the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you solved your problem. This worked for me:

```
function configureBreeze() {
            // configure to use the model library for Angular
            breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

            var accessToken = Security.user.access_token;

            if (Security.user.access_token) {
                // get the current default Breeze AJAX adapter & add header required for the         Web API bearer token mechanism
                var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
                ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
                    headers: {

                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                    },
                };
            }
        }
```

It is a modification of the configureBreeze method found in the datacontext.js script of the [Angular/Breeze SPA template](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breezeangular-template) for asp.net MVC4.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but that doesn't use oData data service. and i think that's what causing a problem described in question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After looking at breeze dataservice for oData i think that it just ignores ajax provider cause it's using *datajs* to do requests. So `instance.setHttp($http);` won't work. I ended up overriding default `request` method in *datajs* like that:

```
    var base = window.OData.request;
    window.OData.request = function (request, success, error, handler, httpClient, metadata) {
        angular.extend(request.headers, { Authorization: $rootScope.token });
        return base(request, success, error, handler, httpClient, metadata);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an sample on the Breeze Website (under OData AJAX): http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/controlling-ajax

```
var oldClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;

var myClient = {
     request: function (request, success, error) {
         request.headers.Authorization = authorization;
         return oldClient.request(request, success, error);
     }
};

OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//instance.defaultSettings = {
//    headers: {
//        'Authorization': 'Bearer...'
//    },
//};

instance.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer...';
```